# Is this 401k statement odd or is it normal?

Tags: united-states, 401k, retirement-plan, benefits

I'm trying to help someone compare benefits for two different companies.  However, we have both interpreted the 401k match statement in the benefits summary differently for one of the companies.

> 35% company match **up to first 6% of employee contribution**.

What would the company contribute if the employee were contributing $10,000 per year as written?  Like $210?  As written, it doesn't even sound useful.

Is this likely a mistake in the benefits summary text or have you actually seen a match setup like this?  I'm thinking this is supposed to say "35% company match up to 6% of employee salary" or something similar rather than up to 6% of employee contribution.  We've requested clarification on this but haven't heard anything yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's almost certainly a confusingly-worded version of

> Company will match employee's contributions, up to 6% of employee's salary, at a 35% rate

or similar, as you expect.  The alternate reading doesn't make sense grammatically - "up to" is incorrect in that phrase (35% match of the first 6% of employee contribution would be okay, but "up to" doesn't parse, since *every* contribution is 100% of itself).

I've more often seen the exact percentage mentioned - but that's because it's always been 50% in my experience, meaning

> 50% company match of employee contributions, capped at 3% of employee salary (when contributing 6% or more of salary)

35% of 6% is 2.10% of employee salary so it's a bit more confusing to put in that terms.

But of course, as with *any* unclear terminology in a benefits package, ask the company HR forthwith.

Comment: As a side note, when did matches become 35% and not 50%?  I remember when they went from 100% to 50%, but...

Comment: I've had various terms on 401k, such as match 2%, 50% on next 2%, and 25% on next 2%, or other wacky schemes. My current employer matches 100% for any amount I contribute, though, which is the best 401k I've ever had the privilege of participating in.

Comment: Yes Joe, you got it. Pretty bad wording.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on the company.  My current employer matches 100% up to 5% with no vesting period.

Comment: Since employee contributions are pretax employers do not have to pay employer side FISA, employer withholding, or state tax.  Short story, any match less than approximately 4% net actually makes them money.  Same thing for other pretax deductions like commuter benefit.  TransitChek makes this case in their benefits pitch.